# How do I combine the `directory' package and the g-brief2 class?

Tags: bibtex, directory

I am struggelling to combine the directory package with the `g-brief2` class. Any help is highly appreciated.

I constructed a working minimal example with the directory package within an `article`, which is working fine for me (all files are downloadable from [here](http://geuz.org/directory/):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[break,longdates]{directory} 
    \directorystyle{address}
    \pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
    \title{\texttt{directory}: Address Book}
    \author{\dir{c.geuzaine}}
    \maketitle
    \nodir{*}
    \directory{family} 
\end{document}
```

And my current `g-brief2` code is presented below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{g-brief2}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[break,longdates]{directory} 
    \directorystyle{address}    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Einstellungen für den Brief

\unserzeichen
%\trennlinien
\lochermarke
\faltmarken
\fenstermarken

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Angaben zum Absender

\RetourAdresse{xxx -- xxx -- xxx}

\Name               {xxx}
\AdressZeileA       {xxx}
\AdressZeileB       {xxx}
\AdressZeileC       {}
\AdressZeileD       {}
\AdressZeileE       {}
\AdressZeileF       {}

\TelefonZeileA      {xxx}
\TelefonZeileB      {xxx}
\TelefonZeileC      {}
\TelefonZeileD      {}
\TelefonZeileE      {}
\TelefonZeileF      {}

\InternetZeileA     {xxx}
\InternetZeileB     {xxx}
\InternetZeileC     {}
\InternetZeileD     {}
\InternetZeileE     {}
\InternetZeileF     {}

\BankZeileA     {}
\BankZeileB     {}
\BankZeileC     {}
\BankZeileD     {}
\BankZeileE     {}
\BankZeileF     {}

\Unterschrift       {xxx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Angaben zum Empfänger

\Postvermerk    {}                   % Einschreiben, etc.
\Adresse        {\dir{microknud}}
\Betreff        {xxx}
\Datum          {xxx}
\Anrede         {xxx}
\Gruss          {Yours sincerely}{1cm}  % Absatz zwischen Brieftext und Grussformel

\Anlagen        {\vspace{1.5cm}
            \underline{xxx}\\ \\
            xxx\\
            xxx\\
            }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Directory Adjustment            
\pagestyle{headings}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Der Brief

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

\title{\texttt{directory}: address books with \LaTeX}
%\maketitle
\author{\dir{microknud}}

% CUSTOM: try e.g. citing just some of the entries
\nodir{*}

% CUSTOM: this has the same effect as \directory[bbl]{family,business}
\directory{family,business} 

%%tth: \par directory generated with \href{directory-address.html}{address-html.bst},
%%tth: \href{directory-email.html}{email-html.bst}, 
%%tth: \href{directory-address.vcf}{address-vcard.bst} and
%%tth: \href{directory-address.ldif}{address-ldif.bst}.




    Text...
    %   \nodir{*}
    %   \directory[german]{addresses}
    %   \directorystyle{letter}

\end{g-brief}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

The following error occurs:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@oddhead ...\headtoname {} \ignorespaces \toname 
                                                  \hfil \@date \hfil \pagena...
l.105 \end{document}
```

Even though I can compile the file now, the result is not appealing. In the address box of the `g-brief2` letter I only get a "?" indicating that before the `\begin{document}` the directory package cannot be used? Moreover, within the letter text the full directory is printed even though I included a no directory print command in my file: `\nodir{*}`

I am still trying to fix these issues. Any ideas and comments are appreciated!

Comment: That's not very minimal, is it?

Comment: I don't get any error when I compile your code. Try removing all generating files and compiling again.